# Moodle 2.7 - "[error] 29515#0" error when restoring courses

Tags: php, restore, moodle

I got this error when trying to restore a course from Moodle 2.5 to the new Moodle 2.7:

```
*2014/08/06 09:56:13 [error] 29515#0: *294 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: instantiating restore controller 5c27aedb3536bb18a04ea62980d025a2
PHP message: setting controller status to 100
PHP message: loading backup info
PHP message: loading controller plan
PHP message: setting controller status to 300
PHP message: checking plan security
PHP message: setting controller status to 500
PHP message: checking plan security
PHP message: checking plan security
PHP message: checking plan security
PHP message: saving controller to db
PHP message: calculating controller checksum c5b1199dbad4393d7c4ae8b6fd44b7d9" while reading upstream, client: 172.18.100.99, server: my.moodle.com, request:
"POST /backup/restore.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "my.moodle.com", referrer: "http://my.moodle.com/backup/restore.php"

2014/08/06 09:56:24 [error] 29515#0: *294 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: loading controller from db
PHP message: checking plan security
PHP message: checking plan security
PHP message: checking plan security
PHP message: saving controller to db
PHP message: calculating controller checksum c5b1199dbad4393d7c4ae8b6fd44b7d9" while reading upstream, client: 172.18.100.99, server: my.moodle.com, request:
"POST /backup/restore.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "my.moodle.com", referrer: "http://my.moodle.com/backup/restore.php"

2014/08/06 09:56:36 [error] 29515#0: *294 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: loading controller from db
PHP message: checking plan security
PHP message: checking plan security
PHP message: checking plan security
PHP message: saving controller to db
PHP message: calculating controller checksum c5b1199dbad4393d7c4ae8b6fd44b7d9" while reading upstream, client: 172.18.100.99, server: my.moodle.com, request:
"POST /backup/restore.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "my.moodle.com", referrer: "http://my.moodle.com/backup/restore.php"

2014/08/06 09:56:44 [error] 29515#0: *294 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: loading controller from db
PHP message: checking plan security
PHP message: checking plan security
PHP message: setting controller status to 600
PHP message: saving controller to db
PHP message: calculating controller checksum c662ab3d320b010e94d1190dfb7dd02f
PHP message: loading controller from db
PHP message: setting controller status to 700
PHP message: saving controller to db
PHP message: calculating controller checksum 8529cea9433173fc64cb2306b679798a
PHP message: loading controller from db" while reading upstream, client: 172.18.100.99, server: my.moodle.com, request: "POST /backup/restore.php HTTP/1.1", u
pstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "my.moodle.com", referrer: "http://my.moodle.com/backup/restore.php"

2014/08/06 09:56:44 [error] 29515#0: *294 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: setting controller status to 800" while reading upstream, client: 172.18.100.99, serv
er: my.moodle.com, request: "POST /backup/restore.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "my.moodle.com", referrer: "http://hsmoodl
e.ssis.edu.vn/backup/restore.php"

2014/08/06 09:57:28 [error] 29515#0: *294 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2356
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2357
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2358
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2359
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2360
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2361
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2362
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2366
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2368
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2370
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2371
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2372
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2375
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2378
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2380
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2381
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2382
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2383
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2385
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2386
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2387
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2388
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2390
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2393
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2394
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2395
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2397
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2406
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2407
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2408
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2410
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2412
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2415
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2416
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2427
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2428
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2430
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2431
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2433
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2434
PHP message: Module not fully restored: id 2435
PHP message:

2014/08/06 09:57:28 [error] 29515#0: *294 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: processing file aliases queue" while reading upstream, client: 172.18.100.99, server: my.moodle.com, request: "POST /backup/restore.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "my.moodle.com", referrer: "http://my.moodle.com/backup/restore.php"

2014/08/06 09:57:29 [error] 29515#0: *294 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: setting controller status to 1000
PHP message: saving controller to db" while reading upstream, client: 172.18.100.99, server: my.moodle.com, request: "POST /backup/restore.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "my.moodle.com", referrer: "http://my.moodle.com/backup/restore.php"*
```

As I tracked down the error, it appeared when I went from step "2. Destination" ► "3. Settings" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue simply by:

- Increase the memory limit of nginx, php
- Increase the execution time of nginx and php